# Push to navigation controller from UICollectionViewCell in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift3

Hi people and please help

Am not using interface builder.

In `AppDelegate`:

```
...
tabBarController.viewControllers = [tabOne, tabTwo, tabThree, tabFour]
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabBarController)
...
```

in tabOne witch is `UIViewController`, lazy load `UITableView` with custom cell and in that cell row I lazy load `UICollectionView`.

And i need to push in `navigationController` some `viewController`?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabBarController)

Comment: use above code.

Comment: @SourLeangChhean sorry about that, I just edited this (my mistake when i type question) . But problem to stays

Answer (score 0):

Please make `tabBarController` as `rootViewController` of `window`

Then create 4 navigationControllers for 4 `viewController` (`tabOne`, `tabTwo`, `tabThree`, `tabFour`) of `tabbarController`.
Like these codes:

```
let viewControllers = [UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabOne), 
                       UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabTwo),
                       UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabThree),
                       UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabFour)]
tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers
window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
```

`TabbarController` is a `containerViewController`, so:

- you need to create 4 `navigationController` for 4 tabs, because they have the particular flows.
- as your code, `tabOne.navigationViewController` is `nil` so you can't `push` other `viewcontroller` because your `navigationController` doesn't belong to `tabOne`, it belongs to `tabBarController`.

Comment: I set it: `tabOne.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "One", image: UIImage(named: "circle"), tag: 1)`  I deliberately left this out, the problem is that the navigationController not pushing new view, the tab bar works perfect

Comment: what navigationController? navigationController of tabbarController, right?

Comment: both, I'm trying to implement both, and only i need to push new ViewController from collectionViewCell, that is in tableViewCell, I try with protocols but didn't work

Comment: Here is a flow [YT](https://youtu.be/9A5Ncq0pEQA), and protocol is very simple (school example) `protocol HomeCellDelegate {
 func openView(_ index: String)
}` and placed in HomeCell (UITableViewCell) which lazy load collectionView...

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to take callback from Collection view cell to the controller or class(which contains the UICollectionView, I think in your case table view cell's .m file)
2. Then callback on the controller which contains the main table view.
3. Now you are on the root view controller of the tab.
4. Push the navigation controller from here (If you already have any navigation controller)

Your case:

> TabBarViewController -> RootViewController(One out of four tab) ->
>   TableView -> TableViewCell -> UICollectionView -> UICollectionViewCell

**Take the callback on RootViewController Then you can do anything.
Remember You should have navigation controller to push another controller.**

Answer (score 0):

I find solution.
In super class for ViewControllers, create function that push to navigation, and from View (Cell) need to delegate self, and call that function. Thanks to all who try to help